# SQL turnover of the day before last year

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm blocking on an SQL query. I am looking to recover the turnover of last year but the day before. For example: we are the 13/08/19 and I wish the turnover of yesterday of last year so 12/08/18.

How can I do that? Here is my request:

```
SELECT SUM(total_paid/1.2)
        FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders
        WHERE o.date_add BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(
        CASE
            WHEN YEAR( DATE_SUB( now(), INTERVAL 364 DAY ) ) = YEAR(now() )
            THEN DATE_SUB(concat(YEAR(now()),'-',MONTH(now()),'-01'), INTERVAL 371 DAY)
            ELSE DATE_SUB(concat(YEAR(now()),'-',MONTH(now()),'-01'), INTERVAL 364 DAY) END, '%Y/%m/%d') AND
        CASE
            WHEN YEAR( DATE_SUB( now(), INTERVAL 364 DAY ) ) = YEAR(now() )
            THEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 371 DAY)
            ELSE DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 364 DAY) END
        AND valid=1
```

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evCuX.jpg)

Thanks for help.

Comment: What type of field is `date_add`?

Comment: exemple: 2018-08-12 10:00:00

Comment: show us table!!

Comment: 13/08/19, is that August 13, 2019, or August 19, 2013? Or perhaps August 19, 1913? (Use proper ISO 8601 date format, i.e. YYYY-MM-DD.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should be able to simplify your query to something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(total_paid/1.2)
FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders
WHERE DATE(o.date_add) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Note that dependent on how you want to treat February 29, you may want to change the expression to

```
CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

In the first form, `2020-02-29` will map to `2019-02-27`, in the second it will map to `2019-02-28`.

Answer (score 0):

{
select sum(your_total_column/1.2) from your_tab
        where now() =(CASE WHEN        mod(year(your_date_column),4) = 0
        THEN          DATE_ADD(your_date_column,INTERVAL 367 DAY)
        ELSE DATE_ADD(your_date_column,INTERVAL 366 DAY));}

The idea is find if your_date_column is leap year if it is leap year then add 367 else add 366 and compare with current date.